# Value Error(): Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10540, 42158]

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, naivebayes

I am woking on text classification data. Where I have applied countVectorize and Tfidf[word level, ngram level, charater level] on the train data of text data.
After applying the tf-idf technique I obtained X_train and Y_train in

"class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix" 
format of shape

1. X_trainc = (42158, 10261)
2. train_y = (42158,)

But When applied to Naive Bayes model for prediction

```
def train_model(classifier, feature_vector_train, label, feature_vector_valid, is_neural_net=False):
    # fit the training dataset on the classifier
    classifier.fit(feature_vector_train, label)

    # predict the labels on validation dataset
    predictions = classifier.predict(feature_vector_valid)


    return metrics.accuracy_score(predictions, train_y)


accuracy = train_model(naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(), X_trainc, train_y, X_testc)
print ("NB, Count Vectors: ", accuracy)
```

I am getting error as follow.

> ValueError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>
> ≪ipython-input-19-140f2a5e54ee> in
>
> 1 # Naive Bayes on Count Vectors
>   ----> 2 accuracy = train_model(naive_bayes.MultinomialNB(), x_train_tf, train_y, x_test_tf)
>
> 3 print ("NB, Count Vectors: ", accuracy)
>
> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
>   samples: [10540, 42158]

Please help how should i solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Accuracy is calculated on the actual output and predicted output of **same data**. You are trying to compare the predictions of test data with the actual outputs of train data. That will not work. Do you have actual ground-truth labels for the `X_testc`?

Comment: not sure if that's a shortcut in your question, but the code you give is not the one that return your error. indeed you write X_trainc and X_testc but the error let us think that train_model was called with x_train_tf and x_test_tf instead. Could your error come from this ?